# Flex Dataprovider caching issue

Tags: apache-flex

I have two combobox controls. If i change combobox A then I am reading from xml and populating combobox B. The xml is loaded into memory in Application's creationComplete method.

When I select values in combobox A and then open combobox B, I am seeing the values correctly, but when I deploy it on the server in a different machine (which is in a different subdomain), then my combobox B values are not cleared and are retained by old selection, when I select the combobox B, then it is getting refreshed.

I am making the dataprovider = null for combobox b, and when I am assigning new collection then i am refreshing the arraycollection as well. 
But still the problem is not solved.

Comment: I was compiling in flex builder with flex sdk 3.2 and while deploying the build it was compiled with flex sdk 3.5 which is not released. 
See the bug details from Adobe bug database.
https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-25155

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was compiling in flex builder with flex sdk 3.2 and while deploying the build it was compiled with flex sdk 3.5 which is not released. See the bug details from Adobe bug database. bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-25155